# Python socket server : Reject connection from address

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a python socket server that listens on a port, and accepts all incoming connections using:

```
(conn, address) = socket.accept()
```

However, I wish to accept connections only from certain ip address.

Currently, I close the connection if the address isn't registered, to accomplish this.

But is there a better way to do this, by directly rejecting connections from unregistered addresses, instead of accepting connections and then closing them?

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible to indicate *Connection refused* to clients from some IP addresses, and to establish the connection to clients from other IP addresses. This is not a Python limitation, but a lower-level, BSD socket layer limitation. You can't do it even from C.

The closest behavior in general you can do in Python is closing the connection quickly after it has been accepted:

```
sock, addr = server_socket.accept()
if addr[0] != '12.34.56.78':
  sock.close()
  return
...
```

Then the client would see the connection being accepted, and very shortly after that the client would see EOF when reading from it, and it wouldn't be able to write to it.

However it's possible to limit by interface (i.e. network card) at *bind* time, by using one of:

```
server_socket.bind(('', 65432))  # Bind on any interface.
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 65432))  # Bind on loopback (localhost clients only).
server_socket.bind(('34.56.78.91', 65432))
```

So in the *127.0.0.1* version, `telnet 127.0.0.1 65432` (as a client) would work, but `telnet myhostname 65432` would yield *Connection refused* (and the `server_socket.accept()` call won't get this connection).

Comment: using sock.close() was working but then out of nowhere it started crashing when ever it was called.  What went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html) you can find the `BaseServer.verify_request(request, client_address)` which tells you this:

> Must return a Boolean value; if the value is True, the request will be processed, and if it’s False, the request will be denied. This function can be overridden to implement access controls for a server. The default implementation always returns True.

Comment: I need a more native implementation than socketserver for an assignment. It it possible to do this using the socket module?

Comment: Well no, you have to receive the incoming connection, but there's not very much overhead with that. I think that what you're doing qualifies as directly rejecting the incoming connection. You haven't started sending or receiving any data yet. And I don't find anything in the docs supporting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft appears to support this functionality via the [SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT socket option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd264794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This appears to require usage of [WSAAccept to accept connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This constant does not appear in pythons socket module on my windows 8 machine.  I don't think there is an option to use WSAAccept via python's builtin socket module.

If I understand correctly, this will allow your server to respond to SYN packets immediately with RST packets when configured to do so instead of finishing the handshake and exchanging FIN packets. Note that usage of this flag removes responsibility to handle connections from the operating system and places it on the application, so there is plenty of room for errors and performance hits to occur. If a performance boost was the goal, it might not be not worth pursuing

It is possible to do at the C level on windows. Pythons [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) module allows interfacing with C code, so it is technically possible to do via a python interface. But it likely requires a non trivial amount of effort. If you are certain you require this feature, it may be less effort to find a C socket library that supports this out of the box, then you could make a ctypes wrapper for that.